# how to copy rds snapshot one region to another region using java api programatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am new in amazon web Services. How to copy RDS Snapshot one region to another Region using aws-sdk-api java programmatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to create the `AmazonRDSClient` in a specific region and when you create the `CopyDBSnapshotRequest` you refer to the snapshot with the full identifier.

Here some pseudo code to copy from us-east zone to eu_central zone

```
AmazonRDSClient rdsClient = new AmazonRDSClient(/*add your credentials and the proper constructor overload*/);
rdsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

CopyDBSnapshotRequest copySnapshot = new CopyDBSnapshotRequest();
copySnapshot.setSourceDBSnapshotIdentifier("arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:snapshot:mysql-instance1-snapshot-20130805");
copySnapshot.setTargetDBSnapshotIdentifier("mysql-instance1-snapshot-20130805-copy");

DBSnapshot dbSnapshot = rdsClient.copyDBSnapshot(copySnapshot);
```

Make sure to review [Java API for RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/package-summary.html) and [Copying a DB Snapshot to Another Region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html)

Comment: Thanks Henri , i got solution in aws java RDS API

Comment: Excellent .. Glad to help